# Laravel migration: using a native PHP enum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, php-8.1

In PHP 8.1, native support for enums were introduced. How can I use them in a Laravel Migration?

My first thought would be something like this, but it does not work.

```php
// migration
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('school_days', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('day_of_week', \App\Enums\DayOfWeek::cases());
        });
    }
```

```php
// DayOfWeek.php
enum DayOfWeek {
    case: Monday;
    case: Tuesday;
    case: Wednesday;
    case: Thursday;
    case: Friday;
    case: Saturday;
    case: Sunday;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that `$table->enum` implemented enums yet but you can like this;

```php
enum DayOfWeek {
    case Monday;
    case Tuesday;
    case Wednesday;
    case Thursday;
    case Friday;
    case Saturday;
    case Sunday;
}


$table->enum('day_of_week', array_map(fn($day) => $day->name, DayOfWeek::cases()));
```

Comment: Won't this break your codebase if when this is deployed you change the internal values of the enum? The migration won't run again every time..

Answer (score 0):

```
enum DayOfWeek {
    case Monday;
    case Tuesday;
    case Wednesday;
    case Thursday;
    case Friday;
    case Saturday;
    case Sunday;
}


$table->enum('day_of_week', array_column(DayOfWeek::cases(), 'name'));
```